# how to get return value through this line

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@C"\mydomain\mysubdomain\testdb\
                                                    app_DATA\DATAESCEL.exe);
```

This method has been called for insert excel sheets value into database. In main method I have write query fro save excel sheet values into database. Please help me how will I get return type value from above method?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow.. Before putting the question here please read all manuals regarding this available on website

Answer (score 0):

This method returns a Process object.

Since you are creating another process from your main application, this process is main's child. However, communication between processes, yet trivial, may complicate your solution (you can search interprocess communication samples in the web).

If you simply want to know if your child process have succeeded, you can test its exit code (any value different from 0 indicates error).

Still, you could simply move this Excel structure to a DLL project and call it, say, as a thread. You would gain both in performance and simplicity.